# using mysql PASSWORD in a codeIgniter query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

hello i need to use the "PASSWORD" fonction of mysql in my codeigniter query

here's my code :

```
$data = array(
        'id' => 'My id',
        'name' => 'My Name',
        'password' => 'My password'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

// **Produces**: INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, password) VALUES ('My id', 'My name', 'My password');

**but i want to produce this query :**
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, password) VALUES ('My id', 'My name', PASSWORD('My password'));

*help me please and i'm sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear but give it ago

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> Database column password varchar 255

```
$new_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$data = array(
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'password' => $new_password
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

On the form to validate password

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php